# AWS boto3 request_spot_fleet pass jinja template as userdata - Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3

I am trying to create `AWS request spot fleet` and specify the `jinja` template as the user-data and pass to the instance and I am following this documentation:
http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

look for - `request_spot_fleet(**kwargs)`:

`'UserData': 'string',`

> UserData (string) -- The user data to make available to the instances.
>   If you are using an AWS SDK or command line tool, Base64-encoding is
>   performed for you, and you can load the text from a file. Otherwise,
>   you must provide Base64-encoded text.

```
     template_file = (current_dir + '/config/user.jinja')
     template = templateEnv.get_template( template_file )
     template_vars = template_vars = { 'var1' : var1 }
     output_template = template.render( template_vars )
     self.output_template = base64.b64encode(output_template).decode("ascii")
```

Error:

```
    self.output_template = base64.b64encode(output_template).decode("ascii")
    File "/usr/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 59, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
    TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

If I pass the `jinja` template as is:

`self.output_template = output_template`

```
com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: 
Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data 
(Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue)
```

Everything works well if I change the UserData to string:

```
self.output_template = base64.b64encode(b'test').decode("ascii")
'UserData': self.output_template,
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The documentation clearly says `Base64-encoding is performed for you` if you use an AWS SDK and you do use an AWS SDK (Boto3). So why are you passing a base64 encoded string, just pass a string.

Comment: not sure so how I can pass the jinja template, if I will do it like this `self.output_template = output_template`, I see an error on aws console `com.amazonaws.services.ec2.model.AmazonEC2Exception: Invalid BASE64 encoding of user data (Service: AmazonEC2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterValue)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python 3 has explicitly require you to specify bytes and string object to prevent codepage encoding issues.

```
# this line only works in python2 
self.output_template = base64.b64encode(output_template).decode("ascii")

# You must convert str to bytes in Python3 
self.output_template = base64.b64encode(output_template.encode("ascii")).decode("ascii")
```

Note : remember to specify your python version when asking question.